# How to display attribute value label instead of numeric value on response of /V1/products/:sku and /V1/products/?searchCriteria?

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, products, rest-api

I have one multi-select attribute(**filter_cuff**). Its value is **Single Button Cuff,Two Button Cuff,Single Button Rounded,Double Button Rounded**. When I call /v1/products/:sku API, it shows response like:

```
custom-attributes{"attribute-code":"filter_cuff","value":"20"}
```

I want to show its value i.e. **Single Button Rounded** instead of **20**. How can it possible?

Please Help me.

Comment: Please guide me asap.